# Change the HOUR in filenames. Batch Script

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have my jpg filenames as EXIF dates. The format of the filename is YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS.JPG. This way it keeps them sequential at all times. Now my camera was set to the wrong hour. So how do I change the HH to -1 hour than it actually is.

For example, if a filename is "2010-11-26-19-15-17_C.jpg", I want to change it to "2010-11-26-**18**-15-17_C.jpg". I have hundreds of files, and they all need to be changed to one hour prior than what is actually in the filenames.

Maybe a batch script? I've used Renamer software, but I can't get it to work just right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that in the worst case you might need to change not only the hour, but also the date, month and year as well (`2010-01-01-00-10-10.jpg` for example will have to become `1999-12-31-23-10-10.jpg`)

If you ignore this caveat, here's the batch file that would allow you to decrement only the hour component of the name.

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /b *.jpg`) do call :ProcessFile %%f

goto :End

:ProcessFile

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,*delims=-" %%i in ("%1") do call :ParseName %1 %%i %%j %%k %%l %%m

goto :End

:ParseName

set /A NEW_HOUR=%5-1

if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "9" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "8" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "7" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "6" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "5" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "4" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "3" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "2" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "1" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%
if "%NEW_HOUR%" == "0" set NEW_HOUR=0%NEW_HOUR%

set OLD_NAME=%1
set NEW_NAME=%2-%3-%4-%NEW_HOUR%-%6

echo Old name : %OLD_NAME%
echo New name : %NEW_NAME%

rem Do copy, rename or whatever you want to do

goto :End

:End
endlocal
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that editing the file name does not affect the EXIF data stored inside the JPG file that includes this same incorrect time stamp.

A good way to deal with this problem in general is to use a tool that can modify the EXIF data, as well as rename the file to match. One such tool is [Exiftool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/) by Phil Harvey. It is free, open source, and portable to many platforms. It even supports Windows.

Quoting from its site:

> Have you ever forgotten to set the date/time on your digital camera before taking a bunch of pictures? ExifTool has a time shift feature that makes it easy to apply a batch fix to the timestamps of the images (ie. change the "Date Picture Taken" reported by Windows Explorer). Say for example that your camera clock was reset to 2000:01:01 00:00:00 when you put in a new battery at 2005:11:03 10:48:00. Then all of the pictures you took subsequently have timestamps that are wrong by 5 years, 10 months, 2 days, 10 hours and 48 minutes. To fix this, put all of the images in the same directory ("DIR") and run exiftool:
>
> `exiftool "-DateTimeOriginal+=5:10:2 10:48:0" DIR`
>
> The example above changes only the DateTimeOriginal tag, but any writable date or time tag can be shifted, and multiple tags may be written with a single command line. Commonly, in JPEG images, the DateTimeOriginal, CreateDate and ModifyDate values must all be changed. For convenience, a shortcut tag called AllDates has been defined to represent these three tags. So, for example, if you forgot to set your camera clock back 1 hour at the end of daylight savings time in the fall, you can fix the images with:
>
> `exiftool -AllDates-=1 DIR`

It also supports renaming files based on a file name template that can not only change the name, but also distribute files into a tree. There is a full example [at the site](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/%7Ephil/exiftool/#filename), but the simple case looks like this

```
exiftool "-FileName<CreateDate" -d "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.%%e" DIR
```

to rename every file in the directory named `DIR` to match your requested template.

Comment: Thanks so much for that info! I will look into and (will probably) use ExifTool.